# Sublime Text Inline Python Documentation

Tags: python, sublimetext

I was looking for a package that gives me inline documentation for python and I came across [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsDW5.png)

Does anyone know what package does this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: It looks like [Anaconda](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda)

Comment: @r-stein thanks! I gave it a try and from what I can tell that's the package. Thank you.